# Axis out of bounds error in Python using PIL and OpenCV 2

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I wanted to change all the pixels in an image to a grey color (r = g = b = 128) if they are in a certain threshold (if the value is between 50 and 150 change it). I imported the image and when i try to process the image it gives me the following error : `IndexError: index 3474 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3474` (the image is 3474x4632).

Here's the code:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

image = Image.open("texture.jpg")
w, h = image.size
print ("%d %d" % (w, h)) #to be sure what the width and height are
im = np.array(image)
for x in range(0, w):
    for y in range(0, h):
        if (im[x][y][0] <= 150 and im[x][y][0] >= 50):
            im[x][y][0] = 128
            im[x][y][1] = 128
            im[x][y][2] = 128

cv2.imwrite("image2.jpg", im)
```

And here's the image i'm trying to convert: https://ibb.co/hnjq4p (too large to upload here). Any ideas about why it doesn't work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that numpy reverses the axis order from PIL. Actually the first index is rows. So you should loop through `w,h = im.shape` or `h,w = image.size` instead. Maybe you can verify that this is correct by comparing `image.size` and `im.shape`?

That said, it will be much better if you do not loop. You can use [masking and broadcasting](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/intro/numpy/numpy.html) to achieve the for loop task like this:

```
im[(im[...,0]<=150)&(im[...,0]>=50)] = 128 # will modify im in place
```

This will be much faster especially on large images like this.

Note that this only checks the first channel of the image to be between 150 and 50. This is what your for loop says so I guess it's what you want.

Comment: You were correct about the axis change. That fixed my problem. Thank you!

Comment: please accept if it worked! Thanks. And try the numpy snippet. Double for loops on images are probably bad code

Comment: I'm new to numpy, so can you tell me what should i put instead of "..." ? Thank you!

Comment: That's what you want! it means 'skip to the last axis slot', and in this case it would be equivalent to `im[:,:,0]` since there are three axes. If there were 7 axes it would be the same as `im[:,:,:,:,:,:,0]`. It's just a shorthand

Answer (score 0):

Please check `im.shape`: you should index your pixels as `im[y,x]` after converting to a `numpy.array`.